# Can we remove/delete controllers, services, factories, directives, etc?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to clear the javascript memory of my app as far as possible. I am thinking if I can remove/delete controllers, services, factories, directives, etc and their scope variables after their use and then reinitialize them whenever required, it would help.

Can we achieve this? If yes, how?

Comment: you can just remove dom element related to scope

Comment: Controller scopes are destroyed when not used. This sounds like an XY problem

Comment: We don't know how your app is setup so we do not have enough information to answer this well.

Comment: Since, services are long living singletons, Is there a way to remove those at least? Just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Services and controllers are instantatied only once in your application it's only raw code so it's pretty ilght.

Unless services layer wield heavy object (cache, variable that contains bunch of items on class level when a local variable is enough, ....) you shouldn't have any memory problem. Note that if you use any 3rd-party library which are not integrated with angular, you may need to listen for $destroy to clean those elements.

Another way would be to change your page setup, maybe some page could be redesign in more pages because theyare too heavy.

I would need more information for the rest.